# Mouse Listener on multiple JLabels acting in a cycle

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I have a map as a background(a JLabel) and i add to it multiple Jlabels(as pawns).I have a mouselistener for the map,so that it moves my pawn to the desired location.But it only works for the last added pawn.why is that?how can i make it cycle through all of my jlabels?I am using the MVC pattern.

I need to assign the mouseListener to the map in order to provide a moving area for the all JLabels.

code from Controller:

```
this.view.addIconListener(new DragMouseAdapter());

    class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
    private Point initialLoc;
    private Point initialLocOnScreen;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  JComponent comp = (JComponent)e.getSource();
  initialLoc = comp.getLocation();
  initialLocOnScreen = e.getLocationOnScreen();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
   /*saySomething("Mouse released; # of clicks: "
                + e.getClickCount(), e);*/
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
   //saySomething("Mouse entered", e);
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
   //saySomething("Mouse exited", e);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


    for(int i = 0; i < 199; i++)
    {
        if((xAxis.get(i) - 15 < e.getX()  && xAxis.get(i) + 15 > e.getX()) && 
            (yAxis.get(i)- 10< e.getY()  && yAxis.get(i) +10 > e.getY() ))
        {
            System.out.println("tada" + (i + 1));
        //System.out.println(x + " " + y);
            view.setCurrentPlayer(model.getCurrentPlayer());
            view.validate();
            //view.addIconListener(this);
            System.out.println(model.getCurrentPlayer());
            view.setPlayerLocation(xAxis.get(i), yAxis.get(i));
            break;
        }
  }
}
```

code from GUI:

```
JLabel yellowPlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("solution/yellow5.png"));
JLabel blackPlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("solution/black5.png"));
JLabel bluePlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("solution/blue5.png"));
JLabel redPlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("solution/red5.png"));
JLabel whitePlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("solution/white5.png"));
JLabel greenPlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("solution/green5.png"));

JLabel map = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("solution/map2.jpg"));

public void addIconListener(MouseListener dragger)
{
    map.addMouseListener(dragger);
}

public void createPanel2()
{   /*middle part of a splitPanel(using 2 JSplitPane) splitted in three*/

    panel2 = new JPanel() ;
    panel2.add(map);
}

public void setPlayerLocation(int x, int y)
{
    if(selectedColour.equals(Colour.Black))
    {

        map.add(blackPlayer);
        blackPlayer.setBounds(x - 13, y - 13, 28, 28);
        blackPlayer.setVisible(true);
    }

    if(selectedColour.equals(Colour.Blue))
    {

        map.add(bluePlayer);
        bluePlayer.setBounds(x - 13, y - 13, 28, 28);
        bluePlayer.setVisible(true);
    }

    if(selectedColour.equals(Colour.White))
    {
        whitePlayer.setBounds(x - 13, y - 13, 28, 28);
        whitePlayer.setVisible(true);
        map.add(whitePlayer);
    }

    if(selectedColour.equals(Colour.Green))
    {
        greenPlayer.setBounds(x - 13, y - 13, 28, 28);
        greenPlayer.setVisible(true);
        map.add(greenPlayer);
    }

    if(selectedColour.equals(Colour.Yellow))
    {
        yellowPlayer.setBounds(x - 13, y - 13, 28, 28);
        yellowPlayer.setVisible(true);
        map.add(yellowPlayer);
    }

    if(selectedColour.equals(Colour.Red))
    {
        redPlayer.setBounds(x - 13, y - 13, 28, 28);
        redPlayer.setVisible(true);
        map.add(redPlayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Without much to go on, you could use [`Container#getComponentAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentAt(java.awt.Point)) to return the component at the given mouse location.

Comment: My GUI , Model and Controller have more than 700 lines of code each :(, I cannot post all. The idea is that the mouseListener takes into account only the last JLabel added to the map(also a JLabel)

Comment: The idea is *not* posting all the code. But a short, runnable example that has a similar issue.